Multivariable Geometric Series
A geometric series is defined as the sum of increasing powers of a single geometric factor. What if we try to generalize the concept to a vector of factors?
Consider this simple series with finitely many geometric factors, where we bump up the exponents one-by-one sequentially: for $\vec{\mathbf{x}}\in \mathbb{C}^N$, define $$f(\vec{\mathbf{x}}) = \sum_{k=0}^{\infty}\left(\prod_{j=1}^N x_j\right)^k \sum_{m=1}^N \prod_{l=1}^m x_l.$$
$N=1$ reduces to the standard geometric series (starting at exponent $1$). The mental picture I have for $f$ is imagining the exponents as positive integer coordinates in the $2$D plane, with $(m,k)$ simply corresponding to the $k$th and $m$th terms in the two sums above, so that we are reading across and up the rows.

Where does this series converge? When it does, is there a closed-form expression for the sum? Maybe it reduces to a simple object with some algebraic manipulation. If there isn't a simple expression for it, can we at least determine some properties of the function $f$?

How is convergence affected by the natural action of the permutation group $S_N$ on $f$?

Is there some integral analog to $f$?

Can $f$ and the above questions meaningfully be generalized to $\mathbb{C}^{\mathbb{N}}$ and with more general exponent-increasing schemes? For instance, one might use the standard Cantor pairing function sequence such that $(1,1),(2,1),(1,2),(3,1),(2,2),(1,3), \ldots$ creates
$$x_1^1 + x_1^1x_2^1 + x_1^2 + x_1^1 x_2^1 x_3^1 + x_1^2 x_2^2 + x_1^3 + \ldots$$
for $\vec{\mathbf{x}}\in \mathbb{C}^{\mathbb{N}}$. (Identical to the $(m,k)$ scheme above, the first index here selects a product string from $x_1$ up to that coordinate, and the second index is applied as an exponent to the selected product string.) Of course, there are infinitely many ways to choose how to increase powers of the geometric factors in the sum, but what are the special and interesting standout choices? I assume the action of $S_{\mathbb{N}}$ on such series' would be difficult to analyze in generality.


